# jQuery - append a same thing twice

Tags: jquery, append

I wan to append a same thing twice. but my code only append once:

```
var target = $('#anID');
var object = target.children('li:last-child').clone();    
$(target).append(object).append(object);
```

tried this too:

```
$(target).append(object);
$(target).append(object);
```

also tried:

```
object.appendTo(target);
object.appendTo(target);
```

but none of them are appending object twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This also works:

```
object.appendTo(target).clone().appendTo(target);
```

Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/Nz8Zh/

Answer (score 2):

```
var target = $('#anID');

target.children('li:last-child').clone().appendTo(target);
target.children('li:last-child').clone().appendTo(target);
```